# Why can I still use access an attribute in rails console without attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, attr-accessible

I am new to learning Rails but my current understanding of `attr_accessible` is that it makes an attribute of a class available outside the class scope.

However without making an attribute `attr_accessible` I am able to access that attribute in a helper method argument in the Rails console.

```
'005 > Todo.create(:todo_item => "Pay internet bill")

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction

  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "todos" ("created_at", "todo_item", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 18 Aug 2012 09:55:33 UTC +00:00], ["todo_item", "Pay internet bill"], ["updated_at", Sat, 18 Aug 2012 09:55:33 UTC +00:00]]

   (339.1ms)  commit transaction

 => #<Todo id: 6, todo_item: "Pay internet bill", created_at: "2012-08-18 09:55
```

However to do the same thing in a controller action :

```
def add

   Todo.create(:todo_item => params[:todo_text])

   redirect_to :action => 'index'

  end
```

In the model I need to specify

```
 attr_accessible :todo_item
```

Why is this attribute accessible in the Rails console but not in a controller method?

Comment: Remember that Rails4 uses strong parameters: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: I am currently working with a tutorial that uses rails 3.2 has the way attr_accessible is used changed in rails 4?

Comment: Yes, no more attr_accessible but strong parameters, read this: http://easyactiverecord.com/blog/2014/04/01/rails4-strong-parameters-and-the-attr-accessible-macro/

Comment: Thanks! So in Rails 4 will the create method in the add action work by default without having to specify attr_accessible in the model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord creates attributes automatically based on the database schema. This is a system superficially similar to but independent from the `attr_accessor` system that's part of core Ruby.

Internally they have nothing in common. An `attr_accessor` is just a wrapper around a simple instance variable but inside a model instance there's a lot more going on.

You can add accessible attributes to your models for things that need to be stored temporarily but not in the database. This is a fairly uncommon thing to do, though.

Comment: so does that mean that I can access instance variables of attirbutes in Rails using the equivalent symbol without having to specify attr_accessor because Rails automatically creates attributes?

Comment: Yes, if it is a property that corresponds to a column in the database you can access it directly off of your model using hash `todo1[:name]` or dot `todo1.name` or `todo1.read_attribute(:name)`